# Is there a strictly monotone, integrable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Im not sure about the above question. Im guessing that there is none, else the question would probably not be asked that way, but i can't really pinpoint where the contradiction lies.

Comment: What is $\Omega$, or what are you assuming about it?  There certainly is in some cases...

Comment: Perhaps it's standard notation, but to me, unknown. What is $\Omega$?

Comment: Im sorry, in our class $\Omega$ is a non-empty, arbitrary set. In this case there should be an $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assume without lost of generality $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ is strictly increasing. Then, we have:
$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \; \mathrm dx \ge \int_0^\infty f(x) \; \mathrm dx \ge \int_0^\infty f(0) \; \mathrm dx$.

Solution:

> From $0\le f(-1) < f(0)$ follows $\int_0^\infty f(0) \mathrm dx = \infty$. Thus, $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: if $f(0)\neq 0$...

Comment: @hjhjhj57 could $f(0) = 0$ happen?

Comment: you're right, my bad.

Comment: So for $f(0) \neq 0$, the integral would be infinite?

Comment: @InspectorPing: Yes, thus $f$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Strict monotonicity implies injectivity on the domain.

Comment: @ user yes, of course! Thanks

Comment: oh, I wrote it just wrong. Strictly monoton only if one to one. sorry.

Comment: And what is the connection between being injective and being integrable?